# Entire container div disappears on android

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, kindle-fire

The whole **width-container** div disappears on android browsers. I have tried using a few various methods such as placing it left top details, translate z, but nothing seems to work.

EDIT: Is anyone skilled enough to solve this!?

http://jsfiddle.net/lagmonster/keeLLjw6/5/

```
html, body, .container { 
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "brandon-grotesque",'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #282828;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

body > .container {
    height: auto; min-height: 100%;
    background-color: white;

}

#intro {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/work/sky_mob.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 200%;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-color: white;
}

#footer a:link{ color:white; } 
#footer a:visited{ color:white; } 
#footer a:hover{ color:#d4af37; } 
#footer a:active{ color:white; }

.footer-half {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;

}

.footer-half-first {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-color: white;
}

.footer-half-second {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.footer-contents {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 22px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.feature {
    position: relative;
}

.feature a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none; /* No underlines on the link */
    z-index: 10; /* Places the link above everything else in the div */
    background-color: #FFF; /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
    opacity: 0; /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
    filter: alpha(opacity=1); /* Fix to make div clickable in IE */
}

img {
    width: 100%;

}


/* ******************************************** */

/* *************** STICKYHEADER *************** */

#header{
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%;

}

#headertwo{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 48px !important;
    background: url(../images/work/topsky.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#header_stick{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

#header_stick img{
    margin-top: -7px;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

.stick {
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    height: 70px !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-color: #d4af37;
    opacity:1;
    z-index: 14;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

.stick img {
    margin-top: -7px!important;
    width: 150px !important;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}


/* ***************************************** */

/* *************** CONTAINER *************** */


.width-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -10px;


    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;

    -webkit-transition: width .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: width .5s ease;
    -o-transition: width .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: width.5s ease;
    transition: width .5s ease;

}


/* ****************************************** */

/* *************** NAVIGATION *************** */

.nav-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;

    font-weight: 700;
}


.nav-logo {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.nav-logo-img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;

}

.nav-logo-text {
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
}

.nav-menu {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%; 
    right: 0px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    height: 30px;
}

.nav-link {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #404040;
    display: none;
}

.work {
    left: -80px;
}

.about {
    left: 38px;
}

.contact {
    left: 172px;
}

.nav-link > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #404040;
}

.nav-link > a:hover,
.nav-link > a.active {
    color: #404040;
}

.nav-link > a:before {
    content: "";
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #d4af37;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.nav-link > a:hover:before,
.nav-link > a.active:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: -7px;
    background-size: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: "brandon-grotesque",'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #282828;
    display: visible;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}


#logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%; left: 0; right: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}



video#bgvid {
    position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -1;
    background: url(../images/work/sky2.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}

video {
    display: hidden;

}

.anchor-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.anchor-point {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 48px;
}

/* ************************************ */

/* *************** WORK *************** */

.folio {
    float:left;
    margin-top: 12px;

    z-index: 12;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    background-color: black;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;

}

.folio:hover {
    -webkit-transition: background-image .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-image .25s ease;
    -o-transition: background-image .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-image .25s ease;
    transition: background-image .25s ease; 
}
/*
.folio:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 90%;
}
*/
.square {

}

.bigsquare {

}

.wide {

}

.tall {

}



/* ******************************************* */

/* *************** TILE IMAGES *************** */

.wideone {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    text-indent: -0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_wide.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: 100%;

    background-color: blue;
}

.wideone:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_wide.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 13;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.wideone:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 13;
}

.supersquare {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    text-indent: -0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 86vw;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_supersquare.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.supersquare:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_supersquare.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 13;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.supersquare:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 13;
}


.tallone {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    text-indent: -0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_tall.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

.tallone:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_tall.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 13;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.tallone:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 13;
}



.squareone {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    text-indent: -0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 86vw;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_square.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.squareone:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_square.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 13;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.squareone:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 13;
}


.talltwo {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    text-indent: -0px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_tall.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.talltwo:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_tall.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 13;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.talltwo:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 13;
}

.squaretwo {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    text-indent: -0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_square.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

.squaretwo:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_square.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 13;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.squaretwo:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 13;
}

.widetwo {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    text-indent: -0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_wide.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.widetwo:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_wide.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 13;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.widetwo:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 13;
}

.squarethree {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    text-indent: -0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_square.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.squarethree:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/work/HiRes/Sprite_square.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: 13;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.squarethree:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 13;
}

/* ***************************************** */

/* *************** CONTAINER *************** */



.descript-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 14;
}

.descript-top {
    width: 100%;
}

.descript-bottom {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 12px;
}

.textbox {
    float: left;
}

.client {
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.text-wide {
    width: 30%;
    top: 0px;
}

.text-small {
    width: 30%;
}

.medium {
    float: left;
}

.category-wide {
    float: right;
    width: 64%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.category-small {
    float: right;
    width: 64%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: right;
}
.other-wide {
    padding-top: 44%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;

}

.other-square {
    padding-top: 96%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.other-supersquare {
    padding-top: 96%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.other-tall {
    padding-top: 200%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/work/icon_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div id="intro">
            <video autoplay loop poster="images/work/sky2.jpg" id="bgvid">
                <source src="" type="video/webm">
                <source src="video/Peri_CloudLoop_BWTV.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="anchor-container">
            <a name="anchor"></a>
            <div class="anchor-point">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="header_stick">

        <div class="nav-container">

            <div class="nav-logo feature">

                <a href="index.html" class="transition">
                </a>
                <div class="nav-logo-img"><img src="images/logo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="nav-logo-text">
                Art Direction &amp; Design</div>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-menu">
                <div class="nav-link contact"><a href="contact.html" class="transition">Contact</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-link about"><a href="about.html" class="transition">About</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-link work"><a href="index.html" class="active transition">Work</a>
                </div>
                <button id="trigger-overlay" type="button">Menu</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">

            <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
            <nav>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html#anchor" class="transition">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html" class="transition">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html" class="transition">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    <div class="width-container">

        <div class="folio wideone feature">
            <div class="descript-container">
                <a href="wideone.html" class="transition"></a>
                <div class="descript-bottom">
                    <div class="client text-wide">Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-wide">Subtitle
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="folio supersquare feature">
            <div class="descript-container">
                <a href="supersquare.html" class="transition"></a>
                <div class="descript-bottom">
                    <div class="client text-wide">Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-wide">Subtitle
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="other-supersquare">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="folio tallone feature" >

            <div class="descript-container">
            <a href="tallone.html" class="transition"></a>
                <div class="descript-bottom">
                    <div class="client text-wide">Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-small">Subtitle
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="other-tall">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="folio squareone feature">

            <div class="descript-container">
            <a href="pedro.html" class="transition"></a>
                <div class="descript-bottom">
                    <div class="client text-small">Title
                    </div>

                    <div class="category-small">Subtitle
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="other-square">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="folio talltwo feature">

            <div class="descript-container">
            <a href="talltwo.html" class="transition"></a>
                <div class="descript-bottom">
                    <div class="client text-wide">Title
                    </div>  
                    <div class="category-small">Subtitle
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="other-tall">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="folio squaretwo feature">
            <div class="descript-container">
            <a href="squaretwo.html" class="transition"></a>

                <div class="descript-bottom">
                    <div class="client text-small">Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-small">Subtitle
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="other-square">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="folio widetwo feature">
            <div class="descript-container">
            <a href="wired.html" class="transition"></a>

                <div class="descript-bottom">
                    <div class="client text-wide">Title
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-wide">Subtitle
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="other-wide">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="folio squarethree feature">

            <div class="descript-container">
            <a href="squarethree.html" class="transition"></a>
                <div class="descript-bottom">
                    <div class="client text-small">Title
                    </div>

                    <div class="category-small">Subtitle
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="other-square">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  


    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="footer-half footer-half-first">
        </div>
        <div class="footer-half footer-half-second">
            <div class="footer-contents">Made by
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure it disappears on Android only? The div has a height of 0 which would in many cases mean, it's not visible.

Comment: It doesn't have a height declared.

Comment: Yeah it's just Android only